# numpy for 64 bit windows

Tags: windows, numpy, python-2.7, 64-bit

I have read several related posts about installing numpy for python version 2.7 on a 64 bit windows7 OS.  Before I try these, does anybody know if the 32bit version will work on a 64bit system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you're using 32-bit Python. If you're using 64-bit Python you'll need 64-bit Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting it from pip and you want a 64 bit version of NumPy, you need MSVS 2008.  pip needs to compile NumPy module with the same compiler that Python binary was compiled with.

The last I checked (this Summer), python's build.py on Windows only supported up to that version of MSVS.  Probably because build.py isn't updated for compilers which are not clearly available for free as compile-only versions.  There is an "Express" version of MSVS 2010, 2012 and 2013 (which would satisfy that requirement).  But I am not sure if there is a dedicated repository for them and if they have a redistribution license.  If there is, then the only problem is that no one got around to upgrading build.py to support the newer vertsions of MSVS.