# 2 questions about Numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

I want to install OpenCV to use it in Python development.
Tutorials ask to install Numpy first. But I am running Windows 7 on a 64 bits processor.

The answer to this question: [Installing Numpy on 64bit Windows 7 with Python 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200137/installing-numpy-on-64bit-windows-7-with-python-2-7-3) says I need to download unofficial binaries for Numpy. So I have 2 questions:

1- Are there official binaries for Numpy since that question was asked 2 years ago ?

2- Can I use what is answered in this question ? 
[numpy for 64 bit windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594953/numpy-for-64-bit-windows). I mean, Can I install directly Python 32 bits on my 64 bits processor and use Numpy 32 bits to avoid troubles ? Please answer me.

Comment: I usually avoid all the troubles of the windows 64bit Python libraries, by using a 32bit Python. There are some alternatives like [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython3.2.5.1/), although I'm not sure whether it is 64 or 32 bit.

Comment: @dmg thank you for the answer. So you mean if I install Python 32 on my 64 machine I may have problems later when I program ?

Comment: Maybe packages like Anaconda http://continuum.io/downloads#all helps you?

Comment: @Dark_Daiver thank you for the answer. I never heard about Anaconda. I visited the link but it does not provide something for 64 bits processor.

Comment: @PythonLearner No, I've always used 32bit Python on my 64 bit machine running Windows, because most python packages for windows are for 32bit Python. I've never ran into any trouble. I've also tried the unofficial windows binaries for 64 bit Python and I recall having some problems with one of the packages, although I cannot remember which one.

Comment: @PythonLearner It's very strange.... check direct link http://09c8d0b2229f813c1b93-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.r79.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda-2.1.0-Windows-x86_64.exe

Comment: @dmg thank you very much for your answer. If people do not answer me, I will choose your suggestion: use everything in its 32 bits version on my computer of 64 bits version

Comment: @Dark_Daiver I thank you for that link, it is very interesting. The only small trouble with it is that it is not available aparently for a 64 bits processor

Comment: @PythonLearner I'm really sorry if i misunderstood you but link that i provide is link to "Windows 64-Bit Python 2.7 Graphical Installer" So is "Windows 64-Bit" not valid version for 64-bits processor? PS Sorry for my poor English

Comment: @Dark_Daiver I'm very sorry, you are right.

Comment: @dmg I did what you said: I installed all the libraries I need in 32 bits version. Everything is fine now. I thought it was impossible on a 64 bits processor. Thank you very much for your answer